# user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported in osx mac

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, recovery, sudoers

hi i am using mac osx i tried to login sudo without password i followed [this](https://romkey.com/2008/11/08/use-sudo-without-a-password-on-your-mac/) tutorial and edited this code in sudoers file

```
chmod +w /etc/sudoers
USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
chmod -w /etc/sudoers
```

but now when i am trying to run any script with sudo command or trying to sudo -i its giving this error

```
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

this only user am using means its root user and i tried this also

`MacBook-Air:~ exepaul$ sudo chmod +w /etc/sudoers Password: exepaul is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

so please help me ;(

Comment: Is your user account definitely an administrator of the mac?  (regardless of the sudoers file)?

Comment: Sounds like you failed to to follow this instruction *"Replace USERNAME with your short username"*

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

su root

nano /etc/sudoers

Then add the user below admin user like below syntax.

%admin ALL=(ALL)  ALL

user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this answer seems to suffer from the same issue as the previous, su / sudo confusion

Answer (score -1):

for my instance , i just
`su root`
then enter self-define user password, then it switch to root!...
then i change root password to new one

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! How does this answer the question? The OP has a problem with using `sudo`, not `su`.